# Tabulate responses for multiple columns by grouping variable with dplyr

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

Hi:I'm new to the plyr/dplyr family but enjoying it. I can see it's massive utility for my own work, but I'm stil trying to get my head around it.
I have a data frame that looks like below.

1) How do I produce a table for each non-grouping variable that shows the distribution of responses within each value of the grouping variable?

2) Note: I do have some missing values and I would like to exclude them from the tabulation.  I realize the summarize_each command will apply the function to each column, but I don't know how to handle the missing values issue in a simple way. I have seen some codes that suggest you have to filter out missing values, but what if the missing values are scattered randomly through the non-grouping variables?

3) Fundamentally, is it best to just use complete cases with dplyr?

```
#library
library(dplyr)
#sample data
group<-sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 100, replace=TRUE)
var1<-sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,NA), 100, replace=TRUE,     prob=c(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.25))
var2<-sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,NA), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.25))
var3<-sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,NA), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.25))
df<-data.frame(group, var1, var2, var3)
#my code
out_df<-df %>%group_by(group)
out_df %>% summarise_each(funs(table))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get counts by `group` for each of `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` if you "melt" your data frame into long form first, which will "stack" the three `var` columns into a single column (`value`) and then create an additional column (`variable`) marking which rows go with which `var`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

#sample data
group <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 100, replace=TRUE)
var1 <- sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,NA), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.25))
var2 <- sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,NA), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.25))
var3 <- sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,NA), 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.15,0.25))

df<-data.frame(group, var1, var2, var3)

out_df <- df %>% 
  melt(id.var="group") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%  # Remove NA
  group_by(group, variable, value) %>%
  summarise(count=n()) %>% 
  group_by(group, variable) %>% 
  mutate(percent=count/sum(count))
```

You can stop the function chain at any point to look at the intermediate steps, which will help in understanding what each step is doing.

Because we grouped by `group`, `variable`, and `value`, we end up with `count` giving us the number of rows for combination of those three columns. Then we group only by `group` and `variable` to calculate the percentage of rows that each value of `count` contributes to each combination of the two grouping variables. (The second `group_by` is not essential, because dplyr drops the last grouping variable after a `summarise` operation (because there will only be one row for each combination of all the original grouping variables) but I prefer to regroup explicitly.)

Here's the final result:

```
out_df

   group variable value count    percent
1      A     var1     1     6 0.26086957
2      A     var1     2     3 0.13043478
3      A     var1     3     6 0.26086957
4      A     var1     4     1 0.04347826
5      A     var1     5     7 0.30434783
...
41     C     var3     1     6 0.25000000
42     C     var3     2     5 0.20833333
43     C     var3     3     4 0.16666667
44     C     var3     4     2 0.08333333
45     C     var3     5     7 0.29166667
```

Comment: Or you could use `dplyr/tidyr` combo

Comment: akrun, and how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If, by tabulate you mean sum then try this:

```
out_df<-df %>%group_by(group)
summarise(out_df,var1=sum(var1,na.rm=TRUE),var2=sum(var2,na.rm=TRUE),var3=sum(var3,na.rm=TRUE))
```

which yields something like this:

```
      group var1 var2 var3
  1     A   67   72   60
  2     B   88   92   97
  3     C   54   77   48
```