# Cross tabulate multiple response questions

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to cross tabulate multiple responses (stored as a set of variables) by a grouping variable. My survey question is: "Which of the following fruits have you had?" The respondent from either geographical Area 1 or Area 2 is then given a list with "1. Orange, 2. Mango, ..." and the resulting data from the yes (1) or no (0) questions is:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(area=rep(c('Area 1','Area 2'), each=6),
                 var_orange=sample(0:1, 12, T),
                 var_banana=sample(0:1, 12, T),
                 var_melon=sample(0:1, 12, T),
                 var_mango=sample(0:1, 12, T))

     area var_orange var_banana var_melon var_mango
1  Area 1          0          1         0         1
2  Area 1          0          0         0         0
3  Area 1          1          1         0         1
4  Area 1          1          0         0         0
5  Area 1          0          1         1         1
6  Area 1          1          1         0         1
7  Area 2          1          0         0         1
8  Area 2          1          1         1         1
9  Area 2          1          1         0         1
10 Area 2          0          0         0         1
11 Area 2          0          1         1         0
12 Area 2          0          0         1         0
```

I would like to get an summary output like this generated in Stata:

```
            |          area          
            |     Area 1      Area 2 |      Total
------------+------------------------+-----------
 var_orange |      50.00       50.00 |      50.00 
 var_banana |      66.67       50.00 |      58.33 
  var_melon |      16.67       50.00 |      33.33 
  var_mango |      66.67       66.67 |      66.67 
------------+------------------------+-----------
      Total |     200.00      216.67 |     208.33
```

I found a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622660/how-to-use-r-for-multiple-select-questions) with a multfreqtable function which gives a one-way summary for my data:

```
multfreqtable = function(data, question.prefix) {
  z = length(question.prefix)
  temp = vector("list", z)

  for (i in 1:z) {
    a = grep(question.prefix[i], names(data))
    b = sum(data[, a] != 0)
    d = colSums(data[, a] )
    e = sum(rowSums(data[,a]) !=0)
    f = as.numeric(c(d, b))
    temp[[i]] = data.frame(question = c(sub(question.prefix[i], 
                                            "", names(d)), "Total"),
                           freq = f,
                           percent_response = (f/b)*100,
                           percent_cases = round((f/e)*100, 2))
    names(temp)[i] = question.prefix[i]
  }
  temp
}

multfreqtable(df, "var_")

$var_
  question freq percent_response percent_cases
1   orange    6               24         54.55
2   banana    7               28         63.64
3    melon    4               16         36.36
4    mango    8               32         72.73
5    Total   25              100        227.27
```

But I am interested in  a two-way summary.

I could use `dplyr` as suggested in a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633168/tabulate-responses-for-multiple-columns-by-grouping-variable-with-dplyr) and get:

```
df %>%
  summarise(orange_pct=round(sum(var_orange,na.rm=TRUE)*100/n(),2), 
            banana_pct=round(sum(var_banana,na.rm=TRUE)*100/n(),2),
            melon_pct=round(sum(var_melon,na.rm=TRUE)*100/n(),2),
            mango_pct=round(sum(var_mango,na.rm=TRUE)*100/n(),2)) 

 orange_pct banana_pct melon_pct mango_pct
1         50      58.33     33.33     66.67
```

But I need a neater table output with marginal column frequencies.

Comment: You could start with `?table`, `?prop.table`, and `?addmargins`. These will get you pretty close.

Comment: The bottom row in your example output is sums, while the right-most column is averages. That inconsistency makes this more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first calculate the values using `dplyr`, then put them in a table using e.g. `knitr::kable`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(area = rep(c('Area 1','Area 2'), each = 6),
                 var_orange = sample(0:1, 12, T),
                 var_banana = sample(0:1, 12, T),
                 var_melon = sample(0:1, 12, T),
                 var_mango = sample(0:1, 12, T))

t1 <- df %>% group_by(area) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
t2 <- df %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))
kable(rbind(t1, t2))
```

And you would get:

```
|area   | var_orange| var_banana| var_melon| var_mango|
|:------|----------:|----------:|---------:|---------:|
|Area 1 |        0.5|  0.6666667| 0.1666667| 0.6666667|
|Area 2 |        0.5|  0.5000000| 0.5000000| 0.6666667|
|NA     |        0.5|  0.5833333| 0.3333333| 0.6666667|
```

To further polish the output to mimick that from Stata:

```
polished <- 100 * rbind(t1, t2) %>%  # Use percentages
  select(-area) %>%                  # Drop "area"
  mutate(Total = rowSums(.[])) %>%   # Add Total
  as.matrix %>% t

kable(polished, digits = 2, col.names = c("Area 1", "Area 2", "Total"))
```

The end result would be:

```
|           | Area 1| Area 2|  Total|
|:----------|------:|------:|------:|
|var_orange |  50.00|  50.00|  50.00|
|var_banana |  66.67|  50.00|  58.33|
|var_melon  |  16.67|  50.00|  33.33|
|var_mango  |  66.67|  66.67|  66.67|
|Total      | 200.00| 216.67| 208.33|
```

Comment: It works but `summarise_each()` raises a warning resulting from applying the `mean()` on the non-numeric area column. To fix this one can restrict the function to act only on the numeric columns by `t2 <- df[-1] %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))`. Another issue is the 'NA' on the 3rd row of the result. I replaced it with 'Total' by `t2$area <- 'Total'`. Could you try edit with that to make the result neater?

Comment: @amo Sure, I have polished my answer to mimick the Stata output. I would rather ignore the warning and leave the NA so that one can simply rbind t1 and t2.

Comment: I noticed that `kable(polished, align='c', digits=2, format = "pandoc", caption = "Title of the table")` makes the output prettier. Might be worth adding?

Answer (score 0):

A different solution using `aggregate` is

```
T1 = aggregate(df[,2:5], list(df$area), sum)
rownames(T1) = T1[,1]
T1 = t(T1[,-1])
T1 = addmargins(T1, 1:2, FUN = c(Total = sum), quiet=TRUE) 
T1
           Area 1 Area 2 Total
var_orange      3      3     6
var_banana      4      3     7
var_melon       1      3     4
var_mango       4      4     8
Total          12     13    25
```

Thanks to @rawr for suggesting the simplification of using `addmargins`.

If you want the table expressed as percentages instead of counts, simply divide by the total count to get the fraction and then change to a percentage.

```
T1 = aggregate(df[,2:5], list(df$area), sum)
rownames(T1) = T1[,1]
T1 = t(T1[,-1])
T1 = T1 * 100 / sum(T1)

T1 = addmargins(T1, FUN = c(Total = sum), quiet=TRUE) 
T1
           Area 1 Area 2 Total
var_orange     12     12    24
var_banana     16     12    28
var_melon       4     12    16
var_mango      16     16    32
Total          48     52   100
```

Comment: `addmargins` can be used on `T1`, `addmargins(T1, 1:2, FUN = c(Total = sum))`

Comment: @rawr  That is a real improvement.  Would you mind if I added it to my solution?

Comment: @rawr Looks nice but would be nicer to have the table values as cell percentages.

Comment: @amo divide the matrix by the total `T1 / 25 * 100` @G5W sounds good, go for it